# Something like let in Ruby

Tags: ruby, lexical-scope

I used to write let-like expressions -- with lexical scope.

So I write my own (sad, but it will fail with multiple threads):

```
# Useful thing for replacing a value of
# variable only for one block of code.
# Maybe such thing already exist, I just not found it.
def with(dict, &block)
  old_values = {}

  # replace by new
  dict.each_pair do |key, value|
    key = "@#{key}"
    old_values[key] = instance_variable_get key
    instance_variable_set key, value
  end

  block.call

  # replace by old
  old_values.each_pair do |key, value|
    instance_variable_set key, value
  end
end
```

I search in google for such constructions (maybe additional block definitions) for ruby, but can't found it. Maybe I loose something? What ruby-people use in such cases?

PS: Sorry for my bad English, you know.

**UPD:** I foget to provide example of usage:

```
@inst_var = 1
with :inst_var => 2 do
  puts @inst_var
end
puts @inst_var
```

output:

```
2
1
```

Comment: What is a let-like expression?

Comment: @Andrew: let-expressions are used in many languages (LISP, Haskell, ML, ...). http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/introsml/core/decls.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea:

```
class Object
  def let(namespace, &block)
    namespace_struct = Struct.new(*namespace.keys).new(*namespace.values)
    namespace_struct.instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

message = let(language: "Lisp", year: "1958", creator: "John McCarthy") do
  "#{language} was created by #{creator} in #{year}"
end
```

Single-value scopping is more explicit because you name the variable(s) in the block arguments. This abstraction has been called `as`, `pipe`, `into`, `scope`, `let`, `peg`, ..., you name it, it's all the same:

```
class Object
  def as
    yield self
  end
end

sum = ["1", "2"].map(&:to_i).as { |x, y| x + y } #=> 3
```

Comment: Two nice suggestions which both result in a clean way to extend the language for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You can't specify the value that you want to initialize, but you can declare a variable as explicitly local to that block:

```
x = 'external value'
puts x
[1,2,3].each do |i; x|
  x = i
  puts x
end
puts x
```

This will result in:

```
external value
1
2
3
external value
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `i` is also local to the block in this example.