# In Ruby, is there a way to executes a block on an arbitrary object, so we can have scoped variables?

Tags: ruby, scope

Take the following example:

```
greeting = "world hello".split.reverse.join(" ")
greeting << ", here me shouting!!"
greeting.upcase!

p greeting # "HALLO WORLD, HERE ME SHOUTING!!"
```

This uses the local variable `greeting` to store a string. Now if we had already used this variable earlier in the code, its original value would now be lost.

```
greeting = "Hi World."

...

greeting = "world hello".split.reverse.join(" ")
greeting << ", here me shouting!!"
greeting.upcase!

p greeting # "HALLO WORLD, HERE ME SHOUTING!!" ... original "Hi World." is gone.
```

So I was thinking if there was a way to create a scope for small snippets like these by using a block. The variable `greeting` would go in the block and would only shadow the outer variable, not override it:

```
greeting = "Hi World."

"world hello".scope do |greeting|
  greeting.split.reverse.join(" ")
  greeting << ", here me shouting!!"
  greeting.upcase!
  p greeting # "HALLO WORLD, HERE ME SHOUTING!!"
end

p greeting # "Hi World."
```

Note the method `scope` I used here. I monkeypatched this method into `Object`. `scope` takes the block and yields it with the local variable of `self`:

```
class Object
  def scope
    yield self
  end
end
```

I don't feel exactly comfortable, to rely on monkey-patching the `Object` class, especially with a method called `scope`, which seems likely to be overridden by other classes, whose instances then can't be scoped like this anymore.

**So, is there a built-in way in Ruby that does this?**

Also - if I have to stay with monkey-patching - I was thinking that `self` might be a better method name than `scope`. Even though also keyword, it can be defined as a method name; it works, I tested it. `self` seems pretty unlikely to be overriden by other classes. It would also fit well to the style of the other most commonly used "block-method" `each`:

#### `collection.each do`

> "Execute the following block on *each* element."

#### `object.self do`

> "Execute the following block on *(your)self*".

**Are there any drawbacks of using `self` as a method name? (other naming suggestions appreciated).**

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010828/something-like-let-in-ruby relevant? Still using the same name in nested scope seems confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked repeatedly. One way is:

```
"world hello".instance_eval do
  ...
end
```

but this is heavy, and is not preferred. A better way suggested is:

```
"world hello".tap do |s|
  ...
  break s
end
```

But in your particular case, method chain is the simplest:

```
"world hello"
.split
.reverse
.join(" ")
.concat(", here me shouting!!")
.upcase
.tap{|s| p s}
```

Comment: This is not about method chaining but about namespaces. My examples were probably not the best to demonstrate what I had in mind. `tap` does exactly what I want, though. Thanks!

Comment: Namespace is relevant when you consider constants. As long as you deal with local variables, namespace is irrelevant.